# Sequelize 2 Many to Many relationship

Tags: database, sequelize.js

I have videos that can be liked by users and commented by users so I need 2 many to many associations.

User model

```
User.belongsToMany(models.Video,{ through: 'user_like_video' });
User.belongsToMany(models.Video, { through: 'user_comment_video' });
```

Video model

```
Video.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'user_like_video'});
Video.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'user_comment_video'});
```

My resulting schema in DB is :

[image]

The many to many relationship between video a tags work well I can use the method `getTags()` to retrieve all the tags from a video but how are created methods when you have 2 (many to many relationship) ?

When I use user.getVideos(), I only get the last relation registered which is here user_comment_video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a way :

```
Video.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'user_like_video', as: 'Like'});
Video.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'user_comment_video',as: 'Comment'});
```

this exposes methods getLike() and getComment()